# Delete duplicate value-items from multiple keys in python dictionary and append to a new dictioanry

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

The original dictionary:

```
d = {'x1': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5'], 'x2': ['P1', 'P2', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8'], 'x3': ['P1', 'P2', 'P6', 'P9', 'P10']}
```

Desired dictonary after deleting duplicate items:

```
d_mod = {'x1': ['P3', 'P4', 'P5'], 'x2': ['P7', 'P8'], 'x3': ['P9', 'P10']}
```

Creates new dictionary of deleted items:

```
d_deleted_items = {'P1':['x1', 'x2', 'x3'],'P2':['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], 'P6':['x2', 'x3']}
```

So far I have achieved:

```
new_list = list(d.items())

for i, d_item in enumerate(new_list):
    i_temp = i
    for v in d_item[1]:
        while i_temp != len(new_list):
            if v in new_list[i_temp+1][1]:
                print(i, v)
                i_temp += 1
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using `itertools` & `collections`.

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
d = {'x1': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5'], 'x2': ['P1', 'P2', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8'], 'x3': ['P1', 'P2', 'P6', 'P9', 'P10']}
d_mod = {}
d_deleted_items = {}
checkVal = Counter(chain.from_iterable(d.values())) # --> {'P1': 3, 'P2': 3, 'P6': 2....
for k, v in d.items():
    for j in v:
        if checkVal[j] == 1:
            d_mod.setdefault(k, []).append(j)
        else:
            d_deleted_items.setdefault(j, []).append(k)
print(d_mod)  
print(d_deleted_items)
```

**Output:**

```
{'x1': ['P3', 'P4', 'P5'], 'x2': ['P7', 'P8'], 'x3': ['P9', 'P10']}
{'P1': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], 'P2': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], 'P6': ['x2', 'x3']}
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this would be to use  `collections.Counter` to quickly count items in the dictionary:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
for i in d.values():
    c.update(i)
```

And then use dictionary & list comprehensions to build your filtered dictionary, referencing the counter to filter the items which appear more than once:

```
d_new = {
    i: [k for k in j if c[k] == 1]
    for i, j in d.items()
}
```

Comment: Pretty much what I was thinking of except with `c = Counter(v for lst in d.values() for v in lst)`

Comment: ooh nice, there's always room for more generators!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer *without* `collections.Counter`.

Create a set of items that represents all invalid entries:

```
entries = set()
invalid = set()

for xs in d.values():
    invalid.update(entries.intersection(xs))
    entries.update(xs)

valid = entries - invalid
```

Which gives:

```
>>> entries
{'P10', 'P4', 'P5', 'P9', 'P7', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P6', 'P8'}

>>> invalid
{'P1', 'P2', 'P6'}

>>> valid
{'P10', 'P4', 'P5', 'P9', 'P7', 'P3', 'P8'}
```

You can then remove these from your dictionary as you please:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d_mod = defaultdict(list)
d_del = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in d.items():
    for x in v:
        if x in valid:
            d_mod[k].append(x)
        else:
            d_del[x].append(k)
```

**NOTE:** This assumes each list does not contain duplicates itself.